# Getting all friends' pictures using the fields parameter doesn't seem to work?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, field, image

I use the JavaScript SDK for Facebook Connect.
Yesterday I loaded all the friends of a logged in user like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,picture&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN&callback=?
```

Using this code I got the id, name, first name **and picture** of all the friends that the logged in user has. This was called using AJAX/jsonp. As I said, it worked yesterday and no modifications have been done to the code since then.

Today I get the id, name and the first name - **no picture(!)** Could this be a glitch in Facebook Graph, has there been any updates that I could have missed or is the above call to the graph API invalid?

Is this a correct way to get the picture of all friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: Bug seems to be fixed now.**

Once again, Facebook proves themselves. Why would anyone just remove something from an API without at least notifying people they are going to do it?

Fyi, I filed this bug report:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/269804093087242

My guess is that it gets ignored or closed as either a duplicate or wontfix and there won't be any recourse.

The issue with the workaround above is that img src url ends up being a http redirect instead of the absolute url like before. That just slows things down.

Comment: As mentioned above, this seems to have been a bug that Facebook has fixed now.

Answer (score 11):

You're right, the picture field is not being returned anymore.  However it is very easy to get the picture URL.  `http://graph.facebook.com/{friendId}/picture`  you can either call that to get it programmatically, or even have that graph call as the src attribute of the image tag `<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{friendId}/picture" />`.

Comment: You sir are a golden goose that lays diamond eggs. Using the graph call directly in the src attribute is much faster than getting the value via ajax and setting the attribute to the response value (especially when doing multiple images)

Comment: I don't believe this will work if you're doing an AJAX call though and setting an img src to the graph since it won't process.

Comment: even me/firends?fields = name,username is also not working in 4.0 :(